# Sampling from Geometric distribution in constant time

Tags: random, probability

I would like to know if there is any method to sample form the Geometric distribution in constant time without using log which can be hard to approximate. Thanks.

Comment: So basically you don't want `floor(log(1-U(0,1))/log(1-p))` ?

Comment: Yes I would like to avoid that because log is not very easy to approximate efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without relying on logarithms, there is no algorithm to sample from a geometric(*p*) distribution in constant expected time.  Rather, on a realistic computing model, such an algorithm's expected running time must grow at least as fast as 1 + log(1/*p*)/*w*, where *w* is the word size of the computer in bits (Bringmann and Friedrich 2013).  The following algorithm, which is equivalent to one in the Bringmann paper, generates a geometric(*px*/*py*) random number without relying on logarithms, and when *px*/*py* is very small, the algorithm is considerably faster than the trivial algorithm of generating trials until a success:

1. Set *pn* to *px*, *k* to 0, and *d* to 0.
2. While *pn**2 <= *py*, add 1 to *k* and multiply *pn* by 2.
3. With probability (1− *px* /*py*)<sup>2<sup>*k*</sup></sup>, add 1 to *d* and repeat this step.
4. Generate a uniform random integer in [0, 2<sup>*k*</sup>), call it *m*, then with probability (1− *px* /*py*)<sup>*m*</sup>, return *d**2<sup>*k*</sup>+*m*. Otherwise, repeat this step.

(The actual algorithm described in the Bringmann paper is in fact much more involved than this; see my note "[On a Geometric Sampler](https://peteroupc.github.io/randmisc.html)".)

REFERENCES:

- Bringmann, K., and Friedrich, T., 2013, July. Exact and efficient generation of geometric random variates and random graphs, in *International Colloquium on Automata, Languages, and Programming* (pp. 267-278).